# GetUserMedia how can i control mic and webcam separetly?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, getusermedia

I want to control audio and video. But it returns me only one result as result. True Or False.

İf audio is allowed and video is disabled it returns false, how can i know ?
I just want to say to user , your audio is Ok , please change your video permission.

```
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video:true  }).then((res) =>{
      console.log(res);
      if(res.active){
  
      }
     
    }).catch( () => {
      alert('CheckYour settings.')

    } )
```

when ı run this code , ı get a response like that
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X2t5.png)